# Is there a system wide limit to the total amount of socket & queue buffer space?

Tags: linux, socket, buffer, message-queuing

in Linux I know that you can tweak the maximum buffer size per socket connection, but is there a system wide limit to the amount of space the buffers can take up and does this apply equally to the size of message queues?

Answer (score 2):

type: `cat /proc/sys/kernel/msgmni` This file defines the system-wide limit on the number of message queue identifiers.
To set it to a new value for this running session with: `# echo 2048 > /proc/sys/kernel/msgmni` , which takes effect immediately.
The system wide default maximum size in bytes of a message queue: 16384 bytes, this can be read from `cat /proc/sys/kernel/msgmnb`

Comment: I'm after determining if there is system wide limit of ALL queues and sockets in total. Or can I have, say, 16384 bytes of queue for *every* descriptor in the system. Or can I just keep having buffers until the system runs out of memory?